# Android - ImageView on splash screen doesn't work

Tags: android, splash-screen

I wanna make splash screen while loading the main activity.

So, I added Splash activity.

```
package com.originerd.tau;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, Main.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    sleep(4500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        logoTimer.start();
    }

}
```

and activity_splash xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" />
```

But when I executed it, the screen shows just black window and shows main activity after 3 seconds. I think it is becuse of image loading time of splash activity. So I added `sleep(1000);` before `Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, Main.class);` line. And it works, but I think it is not that good solution.

I wanna know what is good solution at this situation. The purpose is showing up image while main activity is preparing the contents(It takes around 3 seconds). If there are any solutions(Loading image) instead of splash screen, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sleep` method in `Thread` you can do same easily using `Handler.postDelayed` as:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
         @Override
          public void run() {
             Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, Main.class);
             startActivity(i);
             handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But preparing time of the main activity takes around 3 seconds. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

How large (bytes) is your image? Perhaps the delay could be minimized by shrinking the image size/complexity with graphics tools. As a test, you could try a single color image which should be quite small. That would at least tell you whether the delay is a function of image size.

Comment: The image size is around 100Kb. Is it too big to show at this case? Any other solutions?

Comment: I tried to change imageview to progressbar. But it still isn't shown. Is the only one solution delay like `sleep`?

Comment: 100KB isn't very large; your problem lies elsewhere.